# Relation of unit vectors of spherical and cartesian coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, vectors, coordinate-systems

Okay in the adjoining picture the doubt or query is simple,how did is 
$\hat{\theta}=\frac{\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial \theta}}{\left|\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial \theta}\right|}$

I have seen many youtube videos but still can't find the answer
I am new to electrodynamics and griffiths

[image: A snapshot from Griffiths solution manual]

Comment: @Qmechanic♦ hey man ! its been almost half an hour and no one has answered it yet.If you could answer this question it would be great help

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question?  The text that you posted contains the answer as far as I can tell.

Comment: All I am asking s that where did this identity came from? "$\hat{\theta}=\frac{\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial \theta}}{\left|\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial \theta}\right|}$" rest is simple differentiation that I know well

Comment: $\hat{r}=\frac{\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial r}}{\left|\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial r}\right|}$
 where did this came from ??

Comment: $\hat{\phi}=\frac{\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial \phi}}{\left|\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial \phi}\right|}$ and this one too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the text says, $\frac{\partial {\bf{r}}}{\partial r}$ is a vector which points in the $\hat r$ direction.  If this is not clear, consider the difference quotient:

$$\frac{\partial {\bf{r}}}{\partial r} \equiv \lim_{\delta r \rightarrow 0} \frac{{\bf{r}}(r+\delta r,\theta,\phi) - {\bf{r}}(r,\theta,\phi)}{\delta r}$$

The numerator is an arrow which points from a point $(r,\theta,\phi)$ to the point $(r+\delta r,\theta,\phi)$, and so it points in the $\hat r$ direction.  There is no particular reason that this should be a *unit* vector, though, so if we want the radial unit vector, we should say that

$$\hat r = \frac{\frac{\partial {\bf{r}}}{\partial r}}{\left|\frac{\partial {\bf{r}}}{\partial r}\right|}$$

Precisely the same reasoning holds for $\hat \theta$ and $\hat \phi$.

Comment: so you are saying $\partial \mathbf{r}$ is a vector and $\partial r $ is its magnitude and thus $\hat{r}=\frac{vector}{magnitude}$
and $\partial \mathbf{r}$ is the vector pointing in the direction of the change in direction of $\mathbf{r}$ at any instant ??

Comment: No.  I'm saying that $\frac{\partial {\bf{r}}}{\partial r}$ is a vector which points in the radial direction, and that if you want a *unit* vector, then you need to divide it by its magnitude.

Comment: how is $\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial r}$ is pointing in direction of $\hat{r}$ by that limit term which looks like differentiation

Comment: ${\bf{r}}(r+\delta r,\theta,\phi) - {\bf{r}}(r,\theta,\phi)$ is an arrow pointing from the point $(r,\theta,\phi)$ to the point $(r+\delta r,\theta,\phi)$.  Do you agree?

Comment: i don't understand how $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\mathbf{r}(r+\partial r,\theta,\phi)-\mathbf{r}(r,\theta,\phi)}{\sigma r}$ means it is pointing i radial direction

Comment: yes I do I agree on that its just vector geometry difference between two points

Comment: Do you agree that the arrow is pointing in the radial direction?

Comment: well $\mathbf{r}(r+\partial r,\theta,\phi)$ is a vector and $\mathbf{r}(r,\theta,\phi)$ is another vector their difference points in radial direction how ? I am not able to think it.I think radial direction is in direction of $\mathbf{r}(r+\partial r,\theta,\phi)$

Comment: If you want to get from the point $(r,\theta,\phi)$ to the point $(r+\delta r,\theta,\phi)$, which direction do you go?

Comment: I will have to go in the direction of their difference but that's not the radial direction.radial direction is that of $\mathbf{r}(r+\partial r,\theta,\phi)$

Comment: The direction from the point $(r,\theta,\phi)$ to the point $(r+\delta r,\theta,\phi)$ *is* the radial direction **by definition**.  The radial direction is the direction in which $r$ changes, but $\theta$ and $\phi$ do not.

Comment: ohhh  I got it $\mathbf{r}(r+\partial r,\theta,\phi)$ is extension of $\mathbf{r}(r,\theta,\phi)$ radially so they are actually on same line so they and their differnce points in same direction, now whats the point of the limit term overall

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Exactly the same logic holds for the other directions - ${\bf{r}}(r,\theta+\delta\theta,\phi)-{\bf{r}}(r,\theta,\phi)$ points in the $\hat \theta$ direction, and ${\bf{r}}(r,\theta,\phi+\delta\phi)-{\bf{r}}(r,\theta,\phi)$ points in the $\hat \phi$ direction.

Comment: well I just want you to tell that what is that limit term saying in simple english

Comment: I cannot possibly express this more simply, so you need to be more specific with what you don't understand.